# Upper triangle nested for loop with python set

Tags: python-3.x, set

I have a set of strings, each of which is a key in a dictionary. I need to check each pair once and not check a string with it self.
If it was list I could do something like:

```
for i in range(0, len(mySet)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(mySet)):
        object1, object2 = myDict[i], myDict[j]
        doSomething(object1, object2)
```

How can I acheive this functionality with a set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combinations`, for example:

```
s = {'a', 'b', 'c'}

my_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}

from itertools import combinations

for i, j in combinations(s, 2):
    print(my_dict[i], my_dict[j])
```

Prints:

```
2 1
2 3
1 3
```